# How do I parse rtf text using ruby and parslet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rtf, parslet

I have the following data from a rich text format (RTF) file:

> {\rtf1\ansi\deff3\adeflang1025\n{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fprq2\fcharset0
>   Times New Roman;}{\f1\froman\fprq2\fcharset2
>   Symbol;}{\f2\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0
>   Arial;}{\f3\froman\fprq2\fcharset128 Times New
>   Roman;}{\f4\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset128
>   Arial;}{\f5\fnil\fprq2\fcharset128 Droid Sans
>   Fallback;}{\f6\fnil\fprq2\fcharset128 DejaVu
>   Sans;}{\f7\fswiss\fprq0\fcharset128 DejaVu
>   Sans;}}\n{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red128\green128\blue128;}\n{\stylesheet{\s0\snext0\nowidctlpar{\*\hyphen2\hyphlead2\hyphtrail2\hyphmax0}\cf0\kerning1\hich\af5\langfe2052\dbch\af6\afs24\lang1081\loch\f3\fs24\lang1033
>   Default;}\n{\s15\sbasedon0\snext16\sb240\sa120\keepn\hich\af5\dbch\af6\afs28\loch\f4\fs28
>   Heading;}\n{\s16\sbasedon0\snext16\sb0\sa120 Text
>   body;}\n{\s17\sbasedon16\snext17\sb0\sa120\dbch\af7
>   List;}\n{\s18\sbasedon0\snext18\sb120\sa120\noline\i\dbch\af7\afs24\ai\fs24
>   Caption;}\n{\s19\sbasedon0\snext19\noline\dbch\af7
>   Index;}\n}{\info{\creatim\yr2018\mo7\dy15\hr11\min52}{\revtim\yr0\mo0\dy0\hr0\min0}{\printim\yr0\mo0\dy0\hr0\min0}{\comment
>   OpenOffice}{\vern4140}}\deftab709\n\n{\*\pgdsctbl\n{\pgdsc0\pgdscuse195\pgwsxn12240\pghsxn15840\marglsxn1134\margrsxn1134\margtsxn1134\margbsxn1134\pgdscnxt0
>   Default;}}\n\formshade\paperh15840\paperw12240\margl1134\margr1134\margt1134\margb1134\sectd\sbknone\sectunlocked1\pgndec\pgwsxn12240\pghsxn15840\marglsxn1134\margrsxn1134\margtsxn1134\margbsxn1134\ftnbj\ftnstart1\ftnrstcont\ftnnar\aenddoc\aftnrstcont\aftnstart1\aftnnrlc\n\pgndec\pard\plain
>   \s0\nowidctlpar{\*\hyphen2\hyphlead2\hyphtrail2\hyphmax0}\cf0\kerning1\hich\af5\langfe2052\dbch\af6\afs24\lang1081\loch\f3\fs24\lang1033{\rtlch
>   \ltrch\loch\nI like to read.}\n\par }

Following the example from "Text Processing with Ruby" by Rob Miller, I have the following Parslet Parser:

```
require "parslet"

class Rtf < Parslet::Parser

   rule(:space)                    { str(" ") }

   rule(:hypen)                    { str("-") }

   rule(:integer)                  { match["0-9"].repeat(1) }

   rule(:newline)                  { str("\n") }

   rule(:slash)                    { str("\\") }

   rule(:letter_sequence)          { match["a-z"].repeat }

   rule(:special_chars)            { match["\\\\{}"] }

   rule(:unformatted_text)         { ( special_chars.absent? >> any ).repeat(1).as(:text) }

   rule(:control_word)             { ( slash >> 
                                       letter_sequence.as(:word) >> 
                                       control_delimiter.maybe.as(:delimiter) 
                                     ).as(:control_word) 
                                   }

   rule(:control_delimiter)        { space | ( hypen.maybe >> integer ) | str(";") }


  rule(:group)                     { 
                                      (
                                         str("{") >> 
                                         newline.maybe >>
                                         content >>
                                         newline.maybe >>
                                         str("}") 
                                      )
                                   }

  rule(:content)                   {  
                                     (
                                        unformatted_text | control_word | group
                                     ).repeat
                                   }

  rule(:header)                    {
                                      ( slash >> str("rtf") >> integer.maybe.as(:version) ).as(:rtf) >>  
                                      ( slash >> letter_sequence.as(:charset) ) >>
                                      ( slash >> str("deff") >> integer.maybe ).maybe.as(:deff) >>
                                      color_table.maybe.as(:color_table) >>
                                      newline.maybe
                                   }

  rule(:color_table)               {
                                      newline.maybe >>
                                      str("{") >>
                                      ( slash >> str("colortabl;") ) >> 
                                      color_definition.repeat(1).as(:colors) >>
                                      str("}") >>
                                      newline.maybe  
                                   }

  rule(:color_definition)          {
                                      slash >> str("red") >> (intger.as(:int)).as(:red) >>
                                      slash >> str("green") >> (intger.as(:int)).as(:green) >>
                                      slash >> str("blue") >> (intger.as(:int)).as(:blue) >>
                                      str(";")
                                   }

  rule(:file)                      {
                                      str("{") >>
                                      header.as(:header) >>
                                      content.as(:document) >>
                                      str("}") >>
                                      newline.maybe 
                                   }

  root :file

end
```

Parsing the rtf file with the above Parslet yields:

> (byebug) parsed {:header=>{:rtf=>{:version=>"1"@5},
>   :charset=>"ansi"@7, :deff=>"\deff3"@11, :color_table=>nil},
>   :document=>[{:control_word=>{:word=>"adeflang"@18,
>   :delimiter=>"1025"@26}}, {:text=>"\n"@30}, {:text=>"\n"@374},
>   {:text=>"\n"@431}, {:control_word=>{:word=>"deftab"@1050,
>   :delimiter=>"709"@1056}}, {:text=>"\n\n"@1059}, {:text=>"\n"@1191},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"formshade"@1193, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"paperh"@1203, :delimiter=>"15840"@1209}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"paperw"@1215, :delimiter=>"12240"@1221}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"margl"@1227, :delimiter=>"1134"@1232}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"margr"@1237, :delimiter=>"1134"@1242}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"margt"@1247, :delimiter=>"1134"@1252}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"margb"@1257, :delimiter=>"1134"@1262}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"sectd"@1267, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"sbknone"@1273, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"sectunlocked"@1281, :delimiter=>"1"@1293}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"pgndec"@1295, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"pgwsxn"@1302, :delimiter=>"12240"@1308}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"pghsxn"@1314, :delimiter=>"15840"@1320}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"marglsxn"@1326, :delimiter=>"1134"@1334}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"margrsxn"@1339, :delimiter=>"1134"@1347}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"margtsxn"@1352, :delimiter=>"1134"@1360}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"margbsxn"@1365, :delimiter=>"1134"@1373}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"ftnbj"@1378, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"ftnstart"@1384, :delimiter=>"1"@1392}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"ftnrstcont"@1394, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"ftnnar"@1405, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"aenddoc"@1412, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"aftnrstcont"@1420, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"aftnstart"@1432, :delimiter=>"1"@1441}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"aftnnrlc"@1443, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:text=>"\n"@1451}, {:control_word=>{:word=>"pgndec"@1453,
>   :delimiter=>nil}}, {:control_word=>{:word=>"pard"@1460,
>   :delimiter=>nil}}, {:control_word=>{:word=>"plain"@1465, :delimiter=>"
>   "@1470}}, {:control_word=>{:word=>"s"@1472, :delimiter=>"0"@1473}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"nowidctlpar"@1475, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"cf"@1529, :delimiter=>"0"@1531}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"kerning"@1533, :delimiter=>"1"@1540}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"hich"@1542, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"af"@1547, :delimiter=>"5"@1549}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"langfe"@1551, :delimiter=>"2052"@1557}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"dbch"@1562, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"af"@1567, :delimiter=>"6"@1569}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"afs"@1571, :delimiter=>"24"@1574}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"lang"@1577, :delimiter=>"1081"@1581}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"loch"@1586, :delimiter=>nil}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"f"@1591, :delimiter=>"3"@1592}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"fs"@1594, :delimiter=>"24"@1596}},
>   {:control_word=>{:word=>"lang"@1599, :delimiter=>"1033"@1603}},
>   {:text=>"\n"@1643}, {:control_word=>{:word=>"par"@1645, :delimiter=>"
>   "@1648}}]}

None of the text that is in the RTF file, i.e. "I like to read.", is parsed and i have no clue why.  Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are missing all the groups.

```
rule(:group)                     {
                                  (
                                     str("{") >>
                                     newline.maybe >>
                                     content >>
                                     newline.maybe >>
                                     str("}")
                                  ).as(:group)
                               }
```

Add the 'as(:group)'

Now you get

```
{:header=>
      {:rtf=>{:version=>"1"@5},
       :charset=>"ansi"@7,
       :deff=>"\\deff3"@11,
       :color_table=>nil},
     :document=>
      [{:control_word=>{:word=>"adeflang"@18, :delimiter=>"1025"@26}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@31, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:group=>
         [{:control_word=>{:word=>"fonttbl"@34, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"f"@43, :delimiter=>"0"@44}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"froman"@46, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fprq"@53, :delimiter=>"2"@57}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fcharset"@59, :delimiter=>"0"@67}},
             {:text=>" Times New Roman;"@68}]},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"f"@88, :delimiter=>"1"@89}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"froman"@91, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fprq"@98, :delimiter=>"2"@102}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fcharset"@104, :delimiter=>"2"@112}},
             {:text=>" Symbol;"@113}]},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"f"@124, :delimiter=>"2"@125}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fswiss"@127, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fprq"@134, :delimiter=>"2"@138}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fcharset"@140, :delimiter=>"0"@148}},
             {:text=>" Arial;"@149}]},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"f"@159, :delimiter=>"3"@160}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"froman"@162, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fprq"@169, :delimiter=>"2"@173}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fcharset"@175, :delimiter=>"128"@183}},
             {:text=>" Times New Roman;"@186}]},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"f"@206, :delimiter=>"4"@207}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fswiss"@209, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fprq"@216, :delimiter=>"2"@220}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fcharset"@222, :delimiter=>"128"@230}},
             {:text=>" Arial;"@233}]},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"f"@243, :delimiter=>"5"@244}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fnil"@246, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fprq"@251, :delimiter=>"2"@255}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fcharset"@257, :delimiter=>"128"@265}},
             {:text=>" Droid Sans Fallback;"@268}]},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"f"@292, :delimiter=>"6"@293}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fnil"@295, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fprq"@300, :delimiter=>"2"@304}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fcharset"@306, :delimiter=>"128"@314}},
             {:text=>" DejaVu Sans;"@317}]},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"f"@333, :delimiter=>"7"@334}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fswiss"@336, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fprq"@343, :delimiter=>"0"@347}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fcharset"@349, :delimiter=>"128"@357}},
             {:text=>" DejaVu Sans;"@360}]}]},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@376, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:group=>
         [{:control_word=>{:word=>"colortbl"@379, :delimiter=>";"@387}},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"red"@389, :delimiter=>"0"@392}},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"green"@394, :delimiter=>"0"@399}},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"blue"@401, :delimiter=>"0"@405}},
          {:text=>";"@406},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"red"@408, :delimiter=>"128"@411}},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"green"@415, :delimiter=>"128"@420}},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"blue"@424, :delimiter=>"128"@428}},
          {:text=>";"@431}]},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@434, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:group=>
         [{:control_word=>{:word=>"stylesheet"@437, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"s"@449, :delimiter=>"0"@450}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"snext"@452, :delimiter=>"0"@457}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"nowidctlpar"@459, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:group=>
               [{:control_word=>{:word=>[], :delimiter=>nil}},
                {:text=>"*"@472},
                {:control_word=>{:word=>"hyphen"@474, :delimiter=>"2"@480}},
                {:control_word=>{:word=>"hyphlead"@482, :delimiter=>"2"@490}},
                {:control_word=>{:word=>"hyphtrail"@492, :delimiter=>"2"@501}},
                {:control_word=>{:word=>"hyphmax"@503, :delimiter=>"0"@510}}]},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"cf"@513, :delimiter=>"0"@515}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"kerning"@517, :delimiter=>"1"@524}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"hich"@526, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"af"@531, :delimiter=>"5"@533}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"langfe"@535, :delimiter=>"2052"@541}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"dbch"@546, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"af"@551, :delimiter=>"6"@553}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"afs"@555, :delimiter=>"24"@558}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"lang"@561, :delimiter=>"1081"@565}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"loch"@570, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"f"@575, :delimiter=>"3"@576}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fs"@578, :delimiter=>"24"@580}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"lang"@583, :delimiter=>"1033"@587}},
             {:text=>" Default;"@591}]},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@602, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"s"@605, :delimiter=>"15"@606}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sbasedon"@609, :delimiter=>"0"@617}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"snext"@619, :delimiter=>"16"@624}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sb"@627, :delimiter=>"240"@629}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sa"@633, :delimiter=>"120"@635}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"keepn"@639, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"hich"@645, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"af"@650, :delimiter=>"5"@652}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"dbch"@654, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"af"@659, :delimiter=>"6"@661}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"afs"@663, :delimiter=>"28"@666}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"loch"@669, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"f"@674, :delimiter=>"4"@675}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fs"@677, :delimiter=>"28"@679}},
             {:text=>" Heading;"@681}]},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@692, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"s"@695, :delimiter=>"16"@696}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sbasedon"@699, :delimiter=>"0"@707}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"snext"@709, :delimiter=>"16"@714}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sb"@717, :delimiter=>"0"@719}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sa"@721, :delimiter=>"120"@723}},
             {:text=>" Text body;"@726}]},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@739, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"s"@742, :delimiter=>"17"@743}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sbasedon"@746, :delimiter=>"16"@754}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"snext"@757, :delimiter=>"17"@762}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sb"@765, :delimiter=>"0"@767}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sa"@769, :delimiter=>"120"@771}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"dbch"@775, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"af"@780, :delimiter=>"7"@782}},
             {:text=>" List;"@783}]},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@791, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"s"@794, :delimiter=>"18"@795}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sbasedon"@798, :delimiter=>"0"@806}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"snext"@808, :delimiter=>"18"@813}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sb"@816, :delimiter=>"120"@818}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sa"@822, :delimiter=>"120"@824}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"noline"@828, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"i"@835, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"dbch"@837, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"af"@842, :delimiter=>"7"@844}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"afs"@846, :delimiter=>"24"@849}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"ai"@852, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"fs"@855, :delimiter=>"24"@857}},
             {:text=>" Caption;"@859}]},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@870, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"s"@873, :delimiter=>"19"@874}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"sbasedon"@877, :delimiter=>"0"@885}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"snext"@887, :delimiter=>"19"@892}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"noline"@895, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"dbch"@902, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"af"@907, :delimiter=>"7"@909}},
             {:text=>" Index;"@910}]},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@919, :delimiter=>nil}}]},
       {:group=>
         [{:control_word=>{:word=>"info"@923, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"creatim"@929, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"yr"@937, :delimiter=>"2018"@939}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"mo"@944, :delimiter=>"7"@946}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"dy"@948, :delimiter=>"15"@950}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"hr"@953, :delimiter=>"11"@955}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"min"@958, :delimiter=>"52"@961}}]},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"revtim"@966, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"yr"@973, :delimiter=>"0"@975}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"mo"@977, :delimiter=>"0"@979}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"dy"@981, :delimiter=>"0"@983}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"hr"@985, :delimiter=>"0"@987}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"min"@989, :delimiter=>"0"@992}}]},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"printim"@996, :delimiter=>nil}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"yr"@1004, :delimiter=>"0"@1006}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"mo"@1008, :delimiter=>"0"@1010}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"dy"@1012, :delimiter=>"0"@1014}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"hr"@1016, :delimiter=>"0"@1018}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"min"@1020, :delimiter=>"0"@1023}}]},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"comment"@1027, :delimiter=>" "@1034}},
             {:text=>"OpenOffice"@1035}]},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"vern"@1048, :delimiter=>"4140"@1052}}]}]},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"deftab"@1059, :delimiter=>"709"@1065}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@1069, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@1071, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:group=>
         [{:control_word=>{:word=>[], :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:text=>"*"@1074},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"pgdsctbl"@1076, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@1085, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:group=>
            [{:control_word=>{:word=>"pgdsc"@1088, :delimiter=>"0"@1093}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"pgdscuse"@1095, :delimiter=>"195"@1103}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"pgwsxn"@1107, :delimiter=>"12240"@1113}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"pghsxn"@1119, :delimiter=>"15840"@1125}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"marglsxn"@1131, :delimiter=>"1134"@1139}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"margrsxn"@1144, :delimiter=>"1134"@1152}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"margtsxn"@1157, :delimiter=>"1134"@1165}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"margbsxn"@1170, :delimiter=>"1134"@1178}},
             {:control_word=>{:word=>"pgdscnxt"@1183, :delimiter=>"0"@1191}},
             {:text=>" Default;"@1192}]}]},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@1204, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"formshade"@1206, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"paperh"@1216, :delimiter=>"15840"@1222}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"paperw"@1228, :delimiter=>"12240"@1234}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"margl"@1240, :delimiter=>"1134"@1245}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"margr"@1250, :delimiter=>"1134"@1255}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"margt"@1260, :delimiter=>"1134"@1265}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"margb"@1270, :delimiter=>"1134"@1275}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"sectd"@1280, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"sbknone"@1286, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"sectunlocked"@1294, :delimiter=>"1"@1306}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"pgndec"@1308, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"pgwsxn"@1315, :delimiter=>"12240"@1321}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"pghsxn"@1327, :delimiter=>"15840"@1333}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"marglsxn"@1339, :delimiter=>"1134"@1347}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"margrsxn"@1352, :delimiter=>"1134"@1360}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"margtsxn"@1365, :delimiter=>"1134"@1373}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"margbsxn"@1378, :delimiter=>"1134"@1386}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"ftnbj"@1391, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"ftnstart"@1397, :delimiter=>"1"@1405}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"ftnrstcont"@1407, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"ftnnar"@1418, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"aenddoc"@1425, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"aftnrstcont"@1433, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"aftnstart"@1445, :delimiter=>"1"@1454}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"aftnnrlc"@1456, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@1465, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"pgndec"@1467, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"pard"@1474, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"plain"@1479, :delimiter=>" "@1484}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"s"@1486, :delimiter=>"0"@1487}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"nowidctlpar"@1489, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:group=>
         [{:control_word=>{:word=>[], :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:text=>"*"@1502},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"hyphen"@1504, :delimiter=>"2"@1510}},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"hyphlead"@1512, :delimiter=>"2"@1520}},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"hyphtrail"@1522, :delimiter=>"2"@1531}},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"hyphmax"@1533, :delimiter=>"0"@1540}}]},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"cf"@1543, :delimiter=>"0"@1545}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"kerning"@1547, :delimiter=>"1"@1554}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"hich"@1556, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"af"@1561, :delimiter=>"5"@1563}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"langfe"@1565, :delimiter=>"2052"@1571}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"dbch"@1576, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"af"@1581, :delimiter=>"6"@1583}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"afs"@1585, :delimiter=>"24"@1588}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"lang"@1591, :delimiter=>"1081"@1595}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"loch"@1600, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"f"@1605, :delimiter=>"3"@1606}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"fs"@1608, :delimiter=>"24"@1610}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"lang"@1613, :delimiter=>"1033"@1617}},
       {:group=>
         [{:control_word=>{:word=>"rtlch"@1623, :delimiter=>" "@1628}},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"ltrch"@1630, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"loch"@1636, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@1641, :delimiter=>nil}},
          {:text=>"I like to read."@1642}]},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"n"@1659, :delimiter=>nil}},
       {:control_word=>{:word=>"par"@1661, :delimiter=>" "@1664}}]}
```